# open.spotify.com redirected you too many times

Tags: spotify

Today I was starting a web app I am developing that embeds a Spotify widget player in an iframe. Strangely it doesn't load the widget and instead reports this message

"open.spotify.com redirected you too many times"

I went to [Spotify Widget examples page](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/widgets/examples/) and it shows the same behaviour (here's a [image: snapshot]).

I cleaned the the cache, cookies, but it doesn't seem to sort this. Should I assume there is an API request threshold that I've just hit?

Has anyone have had the same problem and has solution?

Thanks

Comment: Me too. So I think it's their problems, not us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a temporary issue in our service. It's resolved now.

Comment: Sorry, I needed to clean the cache apparently. All working well now, thanks again!

Comment: No worries! You should also check out the new widget page at https://beta.developer.spotify.com/documentation/widgets/

Comment: It’s back again